Bracket expression in python
Why does this assignment work in Python? I can't find this in any documentation.
sign = [1,-1][-5 < 0] # sign = -1
sign = [1,-1][5 < 0] # sign = 1

I assume that the expression in bracket could be True or False, returning the index = 1 (for True) and index = 0 for False, hence [1,-1][0] = 1 and [1,-1][1] = -1. Is that a right understanding?

-5 < 0 is true, which is equivalent to integer 1.  5 < 0 is false, which is equivalent to integer 0.
